# BigCommerce Legacy API Accounts bug

Tags: legacy, bigcommerce

As of today (April 21st) I am having difficulties adding a Legacy API account to my BigCommerce store.

The Legacy API account I created yesterday disappeared when I went to run my API call using Basic Authentication, and now when I'm trying to create a new Legacy API account it's creating a new Custom User instead of giving me the API key that I need.  Since the new user's email is being created as {username}@{store-url}.bigcommerce.com instead of {username}@{store-alias}.com, I'm also not receiving any emails on behalf of this user.

I'm shocked that this is happening, because there has been no mention of changing the Legacy API accounts in the changelog.

See the attached images for what a Legacy API account looks like on my store:
[image: Legacy API Account example]
[image: User created by API account creation]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today.

I discovered (with the help of your example) that the username set under Legacy API Account needed to be the same as the admin user, but without the @domain-name.com.

For example: if your admin is *jane.doe@domain-name.com*, then your Legacy API Account username needs to be *jane.doe*